# Xcode 10.1 with swift language 4.2.1, My Xcode has languages swift 4.2 and How to get Swift 4.2.1

Tags: swift, xcode10.1, swift4.2

I am setting up xcode 10.1, I am having swift language as Swift 4.2, But my jenkins machine need Swift 4.2.1. How to get swift 4.2.1 in my machine.

Comment: 10.1 it is already 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Change swift version from **Build Settings**

[image]